# Prevent subwindow height from shrinking to zero

Tags: vim-windows

Working from home on a travel laptop makes one very stingy with screen space.  I often have Vim taking up the right-most third of the screen and split up into 2-3 vertically stacked subwindows.  Sometimes, I want them equal height (`Ctrl+w`+`=`) while other times, I maximize the height of the current window (`Ctrl+w`+`_`).

With (`Ctrl+w`+`_`), Vim used to leave at least one line of text visible in the other windows.  With Vim 8.2, I find there are zero lines of visible text in the other subwindows, and only their status lines show.  For me, this is not a strong enough reminder that I have other subwindows squished along the top and/or bottom.

**Is there any way to specify that the number of visible lines of text for all subwindows can only drop as low as 1 and not to 0?**

I mean without having to switch into the other windows.

Comment: Hm, can you check what this outputs: `:verbose set winminheight?`

Comment: Aha! It is set to zero, and apparently last set from a *session.x.vim* file that I create to save my tabs, subwindows, and recent files -- and which I subsequently source. Command `:set winminheight=1` fixes the problem. I've never heard of `winminheight` or `wmh` before, and it isn't in `/etc/vimrc` (and I don't have a personal `~/.vimrc`). So it's a mystery how the setting got set to zero. Fingers crossed that it doesn't happen often, but now I know how to fix it.  Thanks!  Would you like to post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour, how much a window can be minimized is influenced by the ['winminheight'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27winminheight%27) option:

> The minimal height of a window, when it's not the current window.
> This is a hard minimum, windows will never become smaller.
> When set to zero, windows may be "squashed" to zero lines (i.e. just a
> status bar) if necessary.  They will return to at least one line when
> they become active (since the cursor has to have somewhere to go.)
> Use 'winheight' to set the minimal height of the current window.
> This option is only checked when making a window smaller.  Don't use a
> large number, it will cause errors when opening more than a few
> windows.  A value of 0 to 3 is reasonable.

Note that by default it is 1, so a window should never be completely collapsed. To find out what the current value is (and where it is set) you can use:

```
:verbose set winminheight?
```

This should give a hint where it is last set so you can adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Christian.  It's odd that the question even needs posting, but Googling `vim minimum-window-height` doesn't turn up the `winminheight` option.  Maybe once this page gets indexed, it will.